# Understanding namespace documentation

Tags: python, namespaces, doxygen

I am struggling to understand how doxygen works with namespaces in Python. A namespace of the name "filename" i.e. `temp.py`, is generated by default. I can also declare new namespaces with the `\package` or `\namespace` command.

However, what I don't understand is why the class below (or any other definition) always appears under the `temp` namespace?

Please help me understand how the namespace command works in doxygen.

**If you know how and why /namespace pr /package commands are used in doxygen, you can bypass the example below and directly answer it.**

```
#filename = temp.py
##\mainpage Main Page Title
#\brief main page title comments  \n




## class class_demo1 \n
#  the class declared below \n
class class_demo1:
        pass

from new_package import *
```

Now, I am adding a new namespace by the name \new_package , added to the temp.py file

```
##\package new_package
#new namespace comments \n
```

I have also created a file named \new_package.py and added the below lines in it:

```
def demo_fun:
    pass

class demo_class:
    pass
```

In the generated documentation, I get \class_demo1 under namespace \temp.
However, the new namespace \new_package.py doesn't display the class and def declared under 
it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put `Demo` class into `new_package` namespace if it is defined in `new_package.temp` module:

```
new_package/
├── __init__.py
│   #   from .temp import Demo
└── temp.py
    #   class Demo:
    #       pass
```

In this case doxygen would need just to reflect the relation that is already in the code.

Comment: @Sebastian can you post some small example code (new or based on my example) to help me better understand it.